# android keyboard press back to close

Tags: android

do anyone know how i know when the keyboard is close? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine whether or not your keyboard his hidden (closed) or not, you can use one of the following approached which return to you an enumerated value indicating whether or not the type of keyboard you're requesting is hidden or not.

```
getResources().getConfiguration().hardKeyboardHidden
```

or

```
getResources().getConfiguration().keyboardHidden
```

The difference is that `keyboardHidden` will take soft keyboards into consideration along with hard keyboards, whereas `hardKeyboardHidden` will only tell you whether or not the hard keyboard is hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but how do i catch the pressing on "back key" to close the keyboard

Comment: you need to handle some sort of KeyEvent (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261914/catch-keypress-with-android or various tutorials online...) You'll of course need to check and make sure that the keyBoard is not hidden when catching a back key press (for your particular scenario).