# How to overide press on keyboard?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Catch keypress with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261914/catch-keypress-with-android)

I want to execute some action when user press Enter button keyboard. How can I get this action?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
         /* This is a sample for handling the Enter button */
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and implement `YourView.setOnKeyListener(this);`

**This was taken directly from** [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261914/catch-keypress-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use InputFilter:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter()
{
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        for (int i = start; i &lt; end; i++)
        {
            if (source.charAt(i) == '\n')
            {
                // Add whatever you want;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```