# How to store button pressed for android app?

Tags: android, button, store, pressed

I am making an android app that needs the user to enter a 4 digit pin from the buttons I made and later on confirm the pin.
I figured I would be able to store the pin as an array.

My question is, how do I store the button pressed?

Here is what I have come up with so far

```
public class EnterPin extends Activity 

{

public int[] pin = new int[4];

public void PinEnterd(View view)

{

int i;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++ )

{

pin = 

}


}

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261914/catch-keypress-with-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need declare a variable to mark the next position of the pin. In the case of the code below, you can save the next position of your pin to `ctr`.

```
public int[] pin = new int[4];
int ctr = 0; //add this to mark the index of your pin

public void PinEnterd(View view)
{
    Button btnPressed = (Button) view; //get access to the button
    int value = Integer.parseInt(btnPressed.getText().toString()); //get the value of the button
    pin[ctr++] = value; //save inputted value and increment counter. next position after 0 is 1.
}
```

- When you inputted the first pin and the value of `ctr` is 0, the inputted pin will be save to `pin[0]`.
- When you inputted the first pin and the value of `ctr` is 1, the inputted pin will be save to `pin[1]`.
- When you inputted the first pin and the value of `ctr` is 2, the inputted pin will be save to `pin[2]`.
- When you inputted the first pin and the value of `ctr` is 3, the inputted pin will be save to `pin[3]`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thank-You.

Answer (score 0):

Just us a boolean :

```
private boolean isPressed = false;

public void PinEntered(View v) {
    if(!isPressed) {
        isPressed = true;
        // Do what you like to do on a Button press here
}
```

If the Pin is incorrect or else and the user as to push the button again just reset `isPressed` to `false` again

Comment: So this will help with checking/confirming the pin? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

how about using something like this? just get the button clicks and add the digits to the array after that you can store it in the sharedpreferences or something...

```
public class EnterPin extends Activity implents OnClickListener{

public int[] pin = new int[4];
public Button[] buttons;


public onCreate(...){
    buttons[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    ...
    buttons[9] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b9);

    buttons[0].addOnclickListener(this);
    ...
    buttons[9].addOnclickListener(this);
}
public ... OnClickListener(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.b1:
        pin[] = 0;
    break;
    ...
    case R.id.b10:
        pin[] = 9;
    break;
}


}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thank you.